# subordinate conjunction usage

Tags: american-english

He was originally from Spain but moved to London in the UK, **since his move to London,** **he has established an export business selling fruit.**

Do we view the prepositional sentence as  subordinate as a whole if it begins with a subordinating conjunction ? In this instance 'since'

He was originally from Spain but moved to London in the UK. However, **since his move to London, he has established an export business selling fruit.**

Answer (score 1):

This second part absolutely deserves its own sentence. The second example (with "However" is acceptable.

The first is a bit of a comma splice. There are two complete sentences with nothing but a comma separating them. The sentences are even particularly closely related. So start a new sentence before "Since", or add a linking adverb like "However".

Comment: There are cases where “since” can link clauses (when it means **because**) but this is not one of them (when it means  **after that time.**)

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/205598/correct-usage-with-conjunctions?noredirect=1#comment397258_205598             What is the distinction between the subordinate usage and the prepositional usage i.e to connect a string of complements.